# How setup Keras model correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, neural-network, keras

I am struggling with building model in Keras. I want to pass all my features as `input=10`, and `output=3`. However, once I run the code below

```
def build_model(input_dim, output_classes):
    print 'Creating model ...', time.time() - start, mprof.memory_usage()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(input_dim=input_dim, output_dim=8, activation=relu))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(input_dim=8, output_dim=6, activation=relu))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=output_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta')
```

I got an error:

```
ValueError: ('shapes (35,9) and (10,8) not aligned: 9 (dim 1) != 10 (dim 0)', (35L, 9L), (10L, 8L))
Apply node that caused the error: Dot22(<TensorType(float32, matrix)>, <TensorType(float32, matrix)>)
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(35L, 9L), (10L, 8L)]
Inputs strides: [(36L, 4L), (32L, 4L)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
```

What are the correct parameters for model initialization in my case?

Comment: Are you sure ```input_dim``` is a scalar?

Comment: Please post the values of `input_dim` and `output_classes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and executed it without errors.(just commented the print as I am using Python 3)

I set input_dim = 10 and output_classes = 3, there was no problems.

May be your are passing a non-integer value for output_classes, if that is the case a range of errors are possible depending on the type of object passed.